# Intellij 14 saying that "Internal caches are corrupted or have outdated format"?

Tags: java, caching, intellij-idea, stack-trace

I've been working on a Java Jersey RESTful web application and everything was going fine until I compiled once again and got the following compiler error.

I've Googled this issue and many suggested doing the `File->Invalidate Caches/Restart...` but this did not work.

I also tried manually deleting the files in the Mac OS X directory: `/Libary/Caches/IntellijIdea14`. This also did not work.

Has anyone ever experienced this before? I'm very confused why this error came and what exactly is causing it. It's certainly putting a delay to my development!

Stack Trace:

```
Information:Internal caches are corrupted or have outdated format, forcing project rebuild: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/grantmcgovern/Dropbox/Developer/Projects/1834Software/GymAPI/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/target/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/target/classes/target/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/.idea/libraries/Maven__org_glassfish_jersey_test_framework_providers_jersey_test_framework_provider_grizzly2_2_17.xml (File name too long)
Information:4/5/15, 10:39 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 29 sec
Error:Internal error: (java.io.FileNotFoundException) /Users/grantmcgovern/Dropbox/Developer/Projects/1834Software/GymAPI/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/target/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/target/classes/target/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/.idea/libraries/Maven__org_glassfish_jersey_test_framework_providers_jersey_test_framework_provider_grizzly2_2_17.xml (File name too long)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/grantmcgovern/Dropbox/Developer/Projects/1834Software/GymAPI/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/target/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/target/classes/target/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/out/artifacts/GymAPI_war_exploded/WEB-INF/classes/.idea/libraries/Maven__org_glassfish_jersey_test_framework_providers_jersey_test_framework_provider_grizzly2_2_17.xml (File name too long)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:221)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.openOutputStream(FileUtil.java:508)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.performCopy(FileUtil.java:460)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.io.FileUtil.copyContent(FileUtil.java:454)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.instructions.FilterCopyHandler.copyFile(FilterCopyHandler.java:40)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.instructions.FileBasedArtifactRootDescriptor.copyFromRoot(FileBasedArtifactRootDescriptor.java:100)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.IncArtifactBuilder.build(IncArtifactBuilder.java:159)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.artifacts.IncArtifactBuilder.build(IncArtifactBuilder.java:50)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTarget(IncProjectBuilder.java:855)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:836)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:894)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:789)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:612)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:352)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:191)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:289)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:124)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:238)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, the following worked (since it's a Maven project):

```
$ mvn clean
```

I suppose cleaning the modules must have done something because it built just fine thereafter. I have to believe this is some sort of Intellij bug.